# read text file returned by URL

Tags: android

This URL return & open text file directly, i just want to read its content how can i do it
    http://translate.google.com.tw/translate_a/t?client=t&hl=en&sl=en&tl=gu&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&oc=1&otf=2&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1&q=this+is+translate+demo

i have tried

```
public static String translate(String sl, String tl, String text) throws IOException{
        // fetch
        URL url = new URL("https://translate.google.com.tw/translate_a/t?client=t&hl=en&sl=" +
                sl + "&tl=" + tl + "&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&oc=1&otf=2&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1&q=" + 
                URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8"));
        Log.d("URL", ":: "+url);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Something Else");
        Log.d("URL", ":: After opening Connection");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        Log.d("URL", ":: br "+br);
        String result = br.readLine();
        br.close();
        // parse
        Log.d("URL", ":: "+result);
        result = result.substring(2, result.indexOf("]]") + 1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String[] splits = result.split("(?<!\\\\)\"");
        for(int i = 1; i < splits.length; i += 8)
            sb.append(splits[i]);
        return sb.toString().replace("\\n", "\n").replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1");
    }
```

Comment: could you explain what you tried till now

Answer (score 1):

If Your Url directly open's the Text File then this code reads the TextFile and print's also as follows:

```
public class URLReader {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
```

}