# How to get text file from the URL objective c?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, google-translate, ios8.1

Currently I'm working on translate application , I referred from [read text file returned by URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603403/read-text-file-returned-by-url) to get the translated text file

https://translate.google.com.tw/translate_a/t?client=t&hl=en&sl=" +
                    sl + "&tl=" + tl + "&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&oc=1&otf=2&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1&q="
 .This is works fine in android while translate, but in iOS it returns text as 
The below code I used to get the file

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://translate.google.com.tw/translate_a/t?client=t&hl=en&sl=en&tl=ta&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&oc=1&otf=2&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1&q=summer"]
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                     timeoutInterval:60.0];

connectionRequest=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"newStr%@",newStr);
```

What I'm doing?please anybody help me to get out of this..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using web service rest of google. Can read the official guide.
[enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs)

Comment: can I get translate for free

Comment: What about clicking on the link. Do you think Diego should read it and tell you, when you could read it yourself?

Comment: @gnasher729 I read it already, it is paid service now.I'm looking for free translate API

Comment: You can read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api

Answer (score 0):

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://translate.google.com.tw/translate_a/t?client=t&hl=en&sl=en&tl=ta&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&oc=1&otf=2&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1&q=summer"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[self addHeaders:request];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[pool release];

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response {

    NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```